# Can I be registered on careers.stackoverflow.com as an employer and a candidate?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, jobs

When I log in, I'm only shown the candidate side of the site.  I can't search for candidates.

Am I missing something?

Why can't I be an employer *and* a candidate?

**Update:**

It seems that this isn't currently allowed but there's a bit of support for it based on comments below.  With that in mind, are the plans to allow this in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, but you need a second OpenID**

It seems to be no problem.

During beta testing, Jeff suggested to me registering a second OpenID with the email address in the form of `myname+employer@example.com` which seems to be supported by most email systems for the email `myname@example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot - currently. A single OpenID cannot be both employer and candidate.

However, it should be possible to implement this and there is no reason why one person could not be both at the same time, or could not be in one role first and second role later.

It is kind of ironic to need two OpenIDs to log into a single site, considering the purpose of the OpenIDs was to reduce the need to create a new identity for each site.

---

There is already upvoted comment to Jeff's answer in this sense, but perhaps having it as a separate answer (which, off course will be upvoted much more times than the Jeff's one) will make more prominent argument such feature should really be implemented.

Comment: Agree with that. I have never needed a second OpenID account, and I want it to stay that way.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot.

A single OpenID cannot be both employer and candidate.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want to allow this?  I'd like to be a candidate, but I also might be looking to hire.

Comment: @Damovisa: so register a separate OpenID then. They're cheap.

Comment: @Shog9 - Oh yeah, that wouldn't be a problem, it's just the logging out and back in again I was hoping to avoid.  One person but two logins...

Comment: I agree that a single user account should be able to be an employer and candidate. I filed my CV so that I could work on it over time, keep it up to date, allow it to grow with me in case I ever need to look for a job. I'm also currently looking to hire a programmer.

Comment: @Mike King: Hear, hear.

Comment: Yeah, similar situation here. I'm building my CV up, but not actively looking yet (I am planning a relocation in the future though, so I will be looking in a while). In the meantime, I'm also the hiring manager for my company and I have slots to fill :)

Comment: Sounds like one of those occasions where the infrequently-required user workaround is much easier than a change! No problem, I'll just use two accounts.