# How do I get to employer view of Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, employer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if you have a careers CV but want to post a job as an employer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer)

I've previously associated my OpenID with semi-finished CV and SO account on Careers. Now I'd like to get an idea of how many developers are available in my area, but http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer redirects me to my own CV.

Is there a way to search for people from my account, or do I have to use a different OpenID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second OpenID.

Update:

Duplicates:

[Can I be registered on careers.stackoverflow.com as an employer and a candidate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/can-i-be-registered-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-as-an-employer-and-a-candidate)

[What if you have a careers CV but want to post a job as an employer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer)