# I have tried Careers as a candidate, but now cannot create an employer account

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs, openid

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I be registered on careers.stackoverflow.com as an employer and a candidate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/can-i-be-registered-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-as-an-employer-and-a-candidate)
>   [What if you have a careers CV but want to post a job as an employer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer)

As the employer side of Careers was not working until now, I tried to see how it looks from the side of a candidate looking for a job. Now I am in a situation where I am unable to access Careers as what I really am, an employer. However, when I log in into Careers with my OpenID, I am taken straight into my job-searching profile and I am given no option to access the employer side.

How can I fix this so that my account is correctly considered an employer?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/can-i-be-registered-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-as-an-employer-and-a-candidate

Comment: While it might be similar, my situation is a little bit different. I tried creating CV because employer role was not available. I would never do it if I knew it will prevent me from accessing the employer interface with my OpenID.

Comment: makes sense... id email team@stackoverflow.com, theyd fix it in like 2 secs

Comment: That seems like a great answer to my question. However, as the question is already closed, it is only a comment and I cannot accept it as I would if it would be an answer.

Comment: I had a similar situation but in reverse, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32818/careers-switch-sides-from-being-an-employer-to-looking-for-a-job-closed, and a proposed solution is juggling with the OpenIDs. For details, read there.