# Careers: Switch sides: from being an employer to looking for a job?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv, employers

At careers you [cannot be **both** employer and job seeker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer) (link to another meta question).

I have a login named **nalply**. Currently I am employer. But as I accumulated reputation with my login, I want to post a CV with it and stop being an employer. I cannot do both, but can I switch from one side to the other one?

Comment: It appears that you didn't even read the question you linked to. Read Jeff's answer again.

Comment: Okay, I tried to rephrase my question. Please reopen my question.

Comment: Click `contact us` and mail the team. I guess they can switch your account by hand.

Comment: Or give your repping account a new OpenID. Then create the other account with the old OpenID. Basically you could try juggling your OpenIDs. IDOpen.

Comment: It worked! Two steps: 1. Add a second OpenID to the repping account. 2. Create a new account at careers. 3. Use the second OpenID to associate with the repping account.

Comment: So, do you agree that this question is NOT an exact duplicate?

Comment: Seems that I cannot count (two steps) :-/