# Can't access careers search after creating a CV

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs, search, employers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I be registered on careers.stackoverflow.com as an employer and a candidate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/can-i-be-registered-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-as-an-employer-and-a-candidate)
>   [What if you have a careers CV but want to post a job as an employer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer)

I've started filling out my CV on `careers.stackoverflow.com`.

I also wanted to check out the search for employers but the page for it: `careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search` always takes me to `careers.stackoverflow.com/cv`

Why am I not able to search through other CVs?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a single OpenID you are either:

- a jobseeker
- an employer.

They are currently mutually exclusive. You can't be both at the same time.

If you're filling out a CV, that means you're not an employer looking to hire and thus won't be able to search other CVs.