# Searching Stack Overflow Careers from the candidate side

Tags: support, jobs, search, employers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t access careers search after creating a CV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/cant-access-careers-search-after-creating-a-cv)

How on earth do I test-drive the search interface for hiring managers?

I seem to be stuck on the candidate side.

Hitting the "I'm hiring" button when not logged in makes me login, tried to redirect to /employer and then redirects to /cv.

Arrrgghh!

Help!

Comment: You can't register the same OpenID as candidate and employer. If you've registered as a candidate you'll need to register a second account to test the employer functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer/30758#30758) to a similar question:

> In Careers terms, you're either a CV owner, or an employer -- you cannot be both.
>
> At least not with the same OpenID.
>
> Thus, if you really want to do this, you must use two different OpenIDs.