# After creating a CV the "We're Hiring" button doesn't work any more

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I be registered on careers.stackoverflow.com as an employer and a candidate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/can-i-be-registered-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-as-an-employer-and-a-candidate)

I tried out the developer search at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search
It worked fine.

Then I clicked on the "Create my CV" button and added a CV to see how it looks like on job-seeker side.

After that I wanted to go back to the search page, but could not. Clicking on "We're Hiring" took me to a page that stated I have a 0% complete CV.

I tried entering the address http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search manually, but it always redirected me to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/can-i-be-registered-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-as-an-employer-and-a-candidate